# Using PHP, how do I echo a different output based on the total number in a form?

Tags: php, forms, session, if-statement, isset

I have a form that calculates a total number using Javascript. The code for the Javascript was taken from [here](http://www.mcfedries.com/javascript/ordertotals.asp).

Once the user submits the form, he is taken to the next page. On the next page, the PHP displays the form total again (this part works), and then, it is supposed to display a different output based on the range of numbers the total is between.

For instance, if the total is between 1 - 250 (say, 100), then X should be displayed. If the total is between 251 - 500 (say, 350), then Y should be displayed. At the moment, it keeps displaying the same output no matter what the total is.

You can see the form in action [here](http://dolphinexpress.com/js/quote-test.php).

Here is the PHP code that I'm using (this will be on the page the user is re-directed to:

```
<?php session_start();
if ($_POST && !empty($_POST['TOTAL'])) {
$_SESSION['TOTAL'] = $_POST['TOTAL'];
} ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>

</head>

<body>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['TOTAL'])) {
echo 'Your total volume is ' . round($_SESSION['TOTAL']) . ' Cubic Feet. The total price for your shipment is:';
} else {
echo 'You did not fill out any details. Please go back.';
}

if (isset($_SESSION['TOTAL']) > 0 && isset($_SESSION['TOTAL']) <= 250) { echo ' $1,000';}

if (isset($_SESSION['TOTAL']) > 250 && isset($_SESSION['TOTAL']) <= 500) { echo ' $2,000';}

if (isset($_SESSION['TOTAL']) > 501 && isset($_SESSION['TOTAL']) <= 1000) { echo ' $4,000';}

else { echo 'Sorry, we do not have a price for that.';}
?>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: your else part is related to last if , if that fails code goes in else path

Comment: if something costs 501, it won't get caught by any of your `IF` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `isset` for your equations (it returns `true` if the value is set and `true` is always `>0` and `<250`). So instead of

```
if (isset($_SESSION['TOTAL']) > 0 && isset($_SESSION['TOTAL']) <= 250) { echo ' $1,000';}
```

say

```
if ($_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 0 && $_SESSION['TOTAL'] <= 250) { echo ' $1,000';}
```

Also use `elseif` to ensure, only one block is executed:

```
if ($_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 0 && $_SESSION['TOTAL'] <= 250) {
    echo ' $1,000';
} elseif ($_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 0 && $_SESSION['TOTAL'] <= 500) {
    echo ' $2,000';
} elseif ($_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 0 && $_SESSION['TOTAL'] <= 1000) {
    echo ' $4,000';
} else {
    echo 'Sorry, we do not have a price for that.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Note:

### This was an expansion of DerVO's [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/632759b2-8c1e-4af8-aced-8919ca513e7e/view-source).  It is largely unnecessary now, but I'm leaving it up for posterity.

Here's an expansion of DerVO's answer:

You're testing `isset($variable) > 0` and `isset($variable) < #`.
Since `isset()` returns either `true` or `false` (or `null`, though that can sometimes be treated as `false`, as in your case), PHP will attempt to make sense of the following comparison (which is what yours boils down to):

`true > 0 && true <= 250`

In PHP, as a loosely typed language, `true` is often interpreted as `1`.  So PHP asks the question, `is 1 larger than 0 AND smaller than 250?`.  It finds that the answer is `yes` and prints your first statement.

All of the other statements it finds to be false, so it skips.

Try checking `isset()` in an outer block:

```
if( isset($_SESSION['TOTAL']) )
{
}
```

And do your output within that block, skipping any of the `isset()` parts.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification rockerest! When I tried a few different variations of the code, I did get 1 occasionally. But now thanks to the answers I got here, everything's working great :)

Answer (score 0):

On line 3, I'd suggest you change

```
$_SESSION['TOTAL'] = $_POST['TOTAL'];
```

to

```
$_SESSION['TOTAL'] = intval($_POST['TOTAL']);
```

This should eliminate any guessing as to whether the script is seeing your input from Javascript as a string.  Then I'd remove the issets from below, it's screwing up your comparisons.  You are comparing true to an integer

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['TOTAL']) > 0 && isset($_SESSION['TOTAL']) <= 250)
```

[`isset`](http://php.net/isset) will only return true or false, whether the variable exists or not. So, if your variable is set, you will always see the first output (`TRUE > 0 && TRUE <= 250`), if it's not set, you will get the `else` block. You probably meant:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['TOTAL']) && $_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 0 && $_SESSION['TOTAL'] <= 250) …
```

Answer (score 0):

The [isset](http://www.php.net/isset) function returns a boolean (true/false) of whether that variable "is set". You are doing an integer comparison with that boolean value which will make it 0 for false and 1 for true. If `$_SESSION['TOTAL']` is set, isset will be converted into 1, you are essentially saying:

```
if (1 > 0 && 1 <= 250) { echo ' $1,000';}
//...continue
```

you will always get the same value. regardless of what the value in $_SESSION['TOTAL'] is. You need to just remove the isset from each `$_SESSION['TOTAL']`. However I would also suggest validating that `$_POST['TOTAL']` is a number ([is_numeric](http://www.php.net/is_numeric), [intval](http://www.php.net/intval)) also.

Answer (score 0):

Maor, i've refactored your `if` statements to a `switch`:

```
switch ($_SESSION['TOTAL']){
    case ($_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 1000):
        echo 'Sorry, we do not have a price for that.';
        break;
    case ($_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 500):
        echo ' $4,000';
        break;
    case ($_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 250):    
        echo ' $2,000';
        break;
    case $_SESSION['TOTAL'] > 0:
        echo ' $1,000';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Sorry, we do not have a price for that.';
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have recommended not using `isset()`. The problem with that is that if the variable is not set, your script will break. So instead we'll query through a general-purpose `get_var()` function.

```
function get_var(&$arr, $key, $default='', $overwrite=false) {
    if (!isset($arr[$key])) return $default;
    if ($arr[$key]) return $arr[$key];
    return $overwrite ? $default : $arr[$key];
}

if (get_var($_SESSION, 'TOTAL', 0) > 0 && get_var($_SESSION, 'TOTAL', 0) <= 250) {
    echo ' $1,000';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (($_SESSION['TOTAL']) > 0 && ($_SESSION['TOTAL']) <= 250) { echo ' $1,000';}
else if (($_SESSION['TOTAL']) > 250 && ($_SESSION['TOTAL']) <= 500) { echo ' $2,000';}
else if (($_SESSION['TOTAL']) > 501 && ($_SESSION['TOTAL']) <= 1000) { echo ' $4,000';}
else { echo 'Sorry, we do not have a price for that.';}
```

use this code in place of your it will work perfectlly